# Change wording in payment popup for Paypal Digital Goods

Tags: paypal, popup

We implemented Paypal Digital Goods for our Flash application to take payment and when user click on 'Pay now', we trigger the Paypal payment popup to show up.  Now, in this popup (generated by Paypal) there is an option for 'buy as a guest' I wonder if it is possible to change the wording to 'Pay via credit or debit card'

​Many thanks

Comment: perhaps it is not possible with Paypal Digital Goods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to modify any of the official Paypal digital goods windows.  There are no API calls, and I'm sure other access is blocked due to security features.  I looked long and hard to change the same wording... it just doesn't exist.  Sorry.